# RadioHead Mesh network communication

Tags: arduino

I'm using the [LilyGO TTGO T-beam](http://www.lilygo.cn/prod_view.aspx?TypeId=50060&Id=1164&FId=t3:50060:3) with ESP32 to create a LoRa mesh network with [RadioHead Library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/index.html). I have met a problem that my mesh client is able to connect with the mesh server, but the server receives 0 bytes from the client. Are there any suggestions? Thanks.
[Current Outcome Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2Xob.jpg)

Settings:

```cpp
#define SCK     5   // GPIO5  -- SX1278's SCK
#define MISO    19  // GPIO19 -- SX1278's MISnO
#define MOSI    27  // GPIO27 -- SX1278's MOSI
#define SS      18  // GPIO18 -- SX1278's CS
#define RST     23  // GPIO14 -- SX1278's RESET --- I tried both of them, none of them works.
#define DI0     26  // GPIO26 -- SX1278's IRQ(Interrupt Request)
#define SELF_ID 1
#define SERVER_ID 254

RHSoftwareSPI spi;
RH_RF95 rf95(SS, DI0, spi);
RHMesh loraMesh(rf95, SELF_ID);  // Server would be SERVER_ID
```

Sending code:

```cpp
int MeshSend(String message) {
  int msgLen = message.length() + 1;
  uint8_t byteData[msgLen] = {'\0'};

  message.getBytes(byteData, message.length());

  if (DEBUG) {
    Serial.print("Sending \'");
    Serial.print((char*)byteData);
    Serial.println("\' to rf95_server, length is " + String(msgLen) + ".");
  }
  sleep(50);  // Stop whole process for cleaning buff
  counter += 50;

  return loraMesh.sendtoWait(byteData, msgLen, SERVER);
}
```

Receiving code:

```cpp
void loop() {
    uint8_t len = RH_MESH_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;  // 250
    uint8_t from;
    driver.setModeRx();
    if (manager.recvfromAck(buf, &len, &from)) {
      if (DEBUG) {
        Serial.print("Got ");
        Serial.print(len);
        Serial.print(" bytes of message from ");
        Serial.print(from, HEX);
        Serial.print(": ");
      }
      Serial.println((char*) buf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, the problem solved, I need to use `manager.available()` to check the status and remove the `manager.setModeRx()`.